# Windows Terminal cursor position

Tags: c#

Windows Terminal cursor position is different than cmd.exe one.

In Windows Terminal, Console.CursorTop seems to refer to the relative position whereas cmd.exe refers to absolute position.
However, I didn't found any solution to use this relative position to calculate an abolute one since everything seems to be relative (WindowTop is always 0 by example).

Here is a simple C# code :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("CursorTop: " + Console.CursorTop);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Here is the output in cmd.exe of 30 lines height:

```
CursorTop: 0
CursorTop: 1
CursorTop: 2
CursorTop: 3
CursorTop: 4
CursorTop: 5
[...]
CursorTop: 45
CursorTop: 46
CursorTop: 47
CursorTop: 48
CursorTop: 49
```

And here is the output in Windows Terminal of 30 lines height:

```
CursorTop: 0
CursorTop: 1
CursorTop: 2
CursorTop: 3
CursorTop: 4
CursorTop: 5
[...]
CursorTop: 29
CursorTop: 29
CursorTop: 29
CursorTop: 29
CursorTop: 29
```

- Why is it different ?
- Is there any option to obtain the same behaviour than cmd.exe ?
- How to write at a specific location without absolute position ?

Configuration:

- PowerShell 1.17.11461.0
- Windows 11 build 22631.2361

Why is it problematic ?

Because I use the cursor position to write at several lines at the same time regarding progress of operations.

Here is an example of the same simple program running in cmd and Terminal that illustrates the problem of not being able to position the cursor with absolute coordinates:

[image: Cmd]
[image: Terminal]

Code of this example:

```
static void Main()
{
    object locker = new object();

    Parallel.For(0, 50, i =>
    {
        int lineNo = -1;

        lock (locker)
        {
            lineNo = Console.CursorTop;
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading " + i.ToString("00") + " [          ]");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep((int)Math.Sqrt(i) * 100);

            lock (locker)
            {
                int topBackup = Console.CursorTop;
                int leftBackup = Console.CursorLeft;

                Console.CursorTop = lineNo;
                Console.CursorLeft = 16 + j;
                Console.Write("=");

                Console.CursorTop = topBackup;
                Console.CursorLeft = leftBackup;
            }
        }
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Console.SetCursorPosition` method can be used to print text to the desired position on the terminal.

There is no delete operation in the terminal. Deletion can be done by writing to the same position again.

Since you have many processes and these processes are simultaneous, you should use `Thread`. Processes should not wait for each other.

Check this example

```
class Process {
        private Point? processPosition { get; set; }
        double dowloadingPercent = 0;
        public int processNumber { get; set; }
        Random random = new Random();
        Thread? processThread;

       
        public void start() {
            // create new thread and run
            // if we use same thread, process wait other process
            processThread = new Thread(this._startDowloading);
            processThread.Start();
        }
       
         void _startDowloading() {

            this.printProcessPercentage();
            while ( dowloadingPercent < 101 ) {
                // print current pertentage
                this.printProcessPercentage();
                dowloadingPercent += 1;
                // wait randomly
                Task.Delay(random.Next(0,1000)).Wait();
            }
        }
        // cursor position to write this process
        Point getLastCursorPosition() {
           return new Point(this.processNumber+2 ,0);
        }
        public void printProcessPercentage() {

            // is set only once. It will be the same in the following writes
            this.processPosition ??= getLastCursorPosition();

            if(this.processPosition != null ) {
             
                // set cursor position to current process start position
                 Console.SetCursorPosition(
                     this.processPosition?.Y ?? 0, 
                     this.processPosition?.X ?? 0
                     );
                // create = array
                
                 var filledArr = Enumerable.Range(1,int.Parse(dowloadingPercent.ToString())).Select(i => "=");
                 //var emptyArr = Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(dowloadingPercent.ToString()),100).Select(i => " ");
                 
                 /// w
                 var str = $"Dowloading {processNumber.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0')} [ {String.Join("",filledArr)} ] %{dowloadingPercent}";
                 Console.WriteLine(str);

                 //Console.SetCursorPosition(0,Console.CursorTop);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
Random random = new Random();
for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
    /// create new process
    var process = new Process() { processNumber = i };
    // start dowloading process
    process.start();
    // wait randomly for other process
    var delay = random.Next(0,500);
    Task.Delay(delay).Wait();
}
```

Output

[image: Output screen]

Comment: That doesn't answer the issue, SetCursorPosition or writing CursorTop do the same. Morover, assuming that you must write on line "2 + processNo" is wrong, it depends on previous output. By the way your example doesn't work (even in the gif you can see line #10 becoming #09 then #00)